# WPF Listview overflow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

How to stop my listview control from overflowing?

When items get added:
[image]

The listview should stop at the red mark.
[image]

Desired result:
[image]

MainWindow.xaml is a hamburger menu with a menu at left and the views.accounts.xaml at right side.

Views.Accounts.xaml:

```
    <UserControl>

<Grid Background="White">
    <!--Define 2 Rows-->
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="48"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<!--Header-->
<Border Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF444444"...>
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<!--Options-->
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"...>

<!--Content area-->
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 20 0 0">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0">
            <ListView Style="{StaticResource VirtualisedMetroListView}"
                      MinHeight="250" Name="accountsListView">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Username" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding username}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Password" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding password}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Email" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding email}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Verified" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding verified}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
                </ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Content="Clear" Width="74" Click="clear_Click"/>
                <Button Margin="10 0 0 0" Content="Export" Width="74"/>
            </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

<!--Settings-->
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10 10 0 10">

</Grid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Since you didn't provide a good [mcve], it's not practical to try to write an actual answer. But based on the tiny bit of information you've shared, it appears that your problem is that, having nested the `ListView` inside the `StackPanel` (an element that gives its children as much room as they want...it just clips whatever exceeds the size), the `ListView` has no way to know it's supposed to show a scrollbar. It's not clear why you're using `StackPanel` here. It seems like you would be better off with two rows in your grid, with the second row having `Height=Auto`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I tried using grid with 2 rows instead of stackpanel. It still didn't worked.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Updated my question with more code.

Comment: The `StackPanel` is the issue here. Can you remove it? If you wrap your `Listview` directly in a Grid, you won't even need to add specific `Scrollviewer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually for this kind of a problem there's few reason:

- ListView is inside StackPanel
- ListView is inside Auto-height Grid Row.
- ListView is inside ScrollViewer.

The easiest way to solve this is to remove the StackPanel and the ScrollViewer controls. ListView includes the ScrollViewer built-in, so you don't have to define it manually.

Also make sure that the Grid's RowDefinition is not set to Height="Auto".

So for example:

```
<!--Content area-->
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 20 0 0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Style="{StaticResource VirtualisedMetroListView}" MinHeight="250" Name="accountsListView">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Username" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding username}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Password" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding password}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Email" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding email}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Verified" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding verified}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Content="Clear" Width="74" Click="clear_Click"/>
        <Button Margin="10 0 0 0" Content="Export" Width="74"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Also make sure that VirtualisedMetroListView -style doesn't contain anything that could affect the ScrollViewer.

Comment: Issue solved. Problem was that the parent grid's row height was set to Auto.